# Как правильно вычислить или вывести малое число?

Tags: visual-c++, ряды

Пытаюсь вычислить частичную сумму знакопеременного ряда `К/ (M*M)`,  где К=1,-1,1,-1...
Известно, что если М стремится к бесконечности, то сумма ряда равна `(Пи*Пи)/12=0.8224670334241132...` (точное значение невозможно, так как есть число Пи.)
И даже получились очень симпатишные результаты!

Но почему-то точность падает на два порядка после 10 в -11 степени. По точности Пи и по разрядности переменных вроде есть запас.
В чем может быть моя ошибка - в типах переменных, в ключах вывода или в методе вычисления? Как это определить?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES  // M_PI = 3.14159265358979323846
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{

    int N=1, M;
    double Summa, Error, Limit, One;

    cout << "Вычисление частичной суммы ряда и сравнение её с пределом.\n\n" << endl << endl;

    Limit = (M_PI*M_PI)/12;

    while (N < 65000)
    {
        Summa=0; 
        Error=0;
        One=1;
        for ( M = 1; M < N; M++) 
        {
            Summa += ( One / (M*M) ); // здесь вычисляем сумму первых членов
            One=-One; // ряд знакопеременный
        }
        Error = Limit - Summa;

        cout << "Cумма " << N << " членов ряда = " << setprecision(10) << Summa << "\t Ошибка = " << setprecision(3) << abs(Error) << endl;
    N=N+1000; // шаг изменения кол-ва членов частичной суммы
    }
    cout << "    Предел суммы ряда: " << setprecision(16) << Limit << endl;

}
```

Cумма   1001 членов ряда = 0.8224665339  Ошибка =     5e-007 - больше членов - меньше ошибка
Cумма   2001 членов ряда = 0.8224669085  Ошибка =  1.25e-007
Cумма   3001 членов ряда = 0.8224669779  Ошибка =  5.55e-008
Cумма   4001 членов ряда = 0.8224670022  Ошибка =  3.12e-008
Cумма   5001 членов ряда = 0.8224670134  Ошибка =     2e-008
Cумма   6001 членов ряда = 0.8224670195  Ошибка =  1.39e-008
Cумма   7001 членов ряда = 0.8224670232  Ошибка =  1.02e-008
Cумма   8001 членов ряда = 0.8224670256  Ошибка =  7.81e-009
Cумма   9001 членов ряда = 0.8224670273  Ошибка =  6.17e-009
Cумма  10001 членов ряда = 0.8224670284  Ошибка =     5e-009
...
Cумма  53001 членов ряда = 0.8224670333  Ошибка =  1.29e-010
Cумма  54001 членов ряда = 0.8224670333  Ошибка =  1.03e-010
Cумма  55001 членов ряда = 0.8224670334  Ошибка =   7.2e-011
Cумма  56001 членов ряда = 0.8224670334  Ошибка =  3.42e-011
Cумма  57001 членов ряда = 0.8224670334  Ошибка =  1.24e-011
Cумма  58001 членов ряда = 0.8224670335  Ошибка =  7.14e-011
Cумма  59001 членов ряда = 0.8224670336  Ошибка =  1.49e-010   <- и вдруг...
Cумма  60001 членов ряда = 0.8224670337  Ошибка =  2.54e-010
Cумма  61001 членов ряда = 0.8224670338  Ошибка =  4.06e-010
Cумма  62001 членов ряда = 0.8224670341  Ошибка =  6.43e-010
Cумма  63001 членов ряда = 0.8224670345  Ошибка =  1.07e-009  <- падает точность...
Cумма  64001 членов ряда = 0.8224670355  Ошибка =  2.05e-009
    Предел суммы ряда: 0.8224670334241132

Comment: Да, до 4294967295, то есть примерно до 4-х миллиардов членов, сумма не не.  

Cумма 10000001 членов ряда = 0.8224670334240735  Ошибка = 3.97e-014  
...  
Cумма 80000001 членов ряда = 0.8224670334240782  Ошибка = 3.5e-014  
Cумма 90000001 членов ряда = 0.8224670334240782  Ошибка = 3.5e-014  
Спасибо VladD. Вопрос можно закрыть! Теперь я могу и на бОльшую точность замахиваться если нужно.

Comment: @qqqq1961, к сожалению, не все так просто

(в комментарий не поместится, поэтому привожу примерчик в "ответе").

Comment: Существует алгоритм ([Аdaptive Precision Floating-Point Arithmetic by Shewchuk (1996)](http://www-2.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/quake/public/papers/robust-arithmetic.ps), который точно находит сумму используя IEEE-754 гарантии для арифметики с плавающей точкой -- это поразительно! [Вот реализация на Питоне `msum()` (можно посмотреть как на исполняемый псевдо-код)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/393090/), ещё [этот алгоритм используется, чтобы реализовать `math.fsum()` функцию из стандартной библиотеки](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a22ef88143b9/Modules/mathmodule.c#l1032).

Answer (score 3):

В принципе, ничего неожиданного нет.

Вы вычисляете с типом `double`, который имеет около 16 значащих цифр. Теперь, если само слагаемое имеет порядок `1e-5 * 1e-5 = 1e-10`, а вы складываете его с частичной суммой, которая имеет величину порядка единицы, дальнейшие разряды теряются, и реально прибавляются лишь последние 6 десятичных цифр:

```
част. сумма:  x.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
слагаемое:    0.0000000000xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
------------------------------------------
результат:    x.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

То есть, точность слагаемого при таком вычислении фактически ограничена `1e-16`. Когда у вас количество слагаемых порядка `1e+5`, суммарная точность получается порядка `1e-11`.

Попробуйте вычислять с конца: сначала наименьшие слагаемые. Тогда частичная сумма будет, возможно, не так сильно понижать точность. (Не уверен, что это поможет.)

---

Обновление: на самом деле тут были *две* проблемы. Первая — переполнение `int`: произведение `M * M` не помещалось в 32-битный `int`, поэтому вычислялось по модулю `2^32`, что, конечно, давало неправильный результат. Ликвидировав это проблему и подняв количество слагаемых, стало возможно добраться до такой точности, где и порядок слагаемых играет роль. Здесь вычисление от маленьких к большим наконец-то дало положительный эффект.

Ещё по теме: [Алгоритм Кэхэна](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) ([здесь на русском](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9A%D1%8D%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%B0)).

Comment: Ох. Об этом я и не подумал. А правда, какой у вас максимальный размер `int` (и `long`)? Если у вас `int` 32-разрядный, попробуйте вывести произведение `65000 * 65000`, тогда станет понятна причина проблемы.

Comment: @qqqq1961: Я к тому, что у вас наверняка переполнение, и `65000 * 65000` «не вписывается» в `int`.

Comment: int main()  
{ 
 long k = 65000;  
 unsigned long uk=65000, uk2 = 65000000;  

 cout.precision(20); 

 cout << "65000*65000 = " << 65000*65000 << endl;  
 cout << "k*k = " << k*k << endl;  
 cout << "uk*uk = " << uk*uk << endl << endl;  

 cout << "65000000*65000000 = " << 65000000*65000000 << endl;  
 cout << "uk2*uk2 = " << uk2*uk2 << endl << endl;  

}  

65000*65000 = -69967296  
k*k = -69967296  
uk*uk = 4225000000 - правильно  

65000000*65000000 = 2016219136  
uk2*uk2 = 2016219136  
а должно быть 4225000000000000

Comment: @qqqq1961: Вот! Это, наверное, основная причина вашей проблемы.

Попробуйте так:

    Summa += ( (One / M) / M) );

Comment: нет уж, спасибо! в задании делим единицу на квадрат Мы.
Да, в принципе, все заработало гладко до 14 степени и хватит пока, Вы помогли сдвинуться!.
ПодскАжите как сумму считать обратно? (От меньших к большему) (хочу проверить, изменится ли точность, а то есть подозрения...)

Comment: @qqqq1961: Ну, возьмите `unsigned long long` тогда.

Чтобы развернуть цикл, напишите

    for ( M = N - 1; M > 0; M-- )

(и не забудьте правильно вычислить начальный знак `One` в зависимости от чётности `N`).

Comment: unsigned long int N=4294967295;  
double Summa=0,Error,Limit,One=1,M;  
Limit = (M_PI*M_PI)/12;  

for (M=1; M<N; M++) {Summa +=One/(M*M); One=-One;}  
Error = Limit - Summa;  
Cумма 4294967295 членов= 0.82246703342407823 Ошибка = 3.5e-014  
  
Summa=0; One=1; N=1;  
for (M=102669069; M>0; M--) {Summa += One/(M*M); One=-One;}  
Error = Limit - Summa;  
Cумма 102669069 членов = 0.82246703342411331  Ошибка = 1.11e-016  
  
Summa=0; One=-1; N=1;  
for (M=102669070; M>0; M-- ) {Summa += One/(M*M); One=-One;}  
Error = Limit - Summa;  
Cумма 102669070 членов = 0.8224670334241132   Ошибка = 0

Comment: Уважаемые коллеги! Почему при суммировании в обратном порядке уже при ста лимонах членов получена ошибка НОЛЬ (гениальная догадка VladaD), а при прямом даже при 4-х миллиардах всего 10 в -14 и конца не видно?! Это мне напоминает, как меряли удава "от головы до хвоста..."

И еще, ряд сходящийся из-за ошибки, что ли?! Или я нечаянно опроверг каку-нить аксиому параллельных, и они пересеклись? Куда бежать за нобелевкой???

Comment: @qqqq1961: Сложение чисел типа `double` **неассоциативно** (хотя и коммутативно). Простой пример: если у нас действительные числа размером в 2 десятичных знака:

    (((1 + 0.07) + 0.06) + 0.05) + 0.04 = ((1 + 0.06) + 0.05) + 0.04 = (1 + 0.05) + 0.04 = 1 + 0.04 = 1
    1 + (0.07 + (0.06 + (0.05 + 0.04))) = 1 + (0.07 + (0.06 + 0.09)) = 1 + (0.07 + 0.15) = 1 + 0.22 = 1.2

У вас происходит то же самое, только в бóльших масштабах. (У меня как раз описано в ответе.)

Comment: @qqqq1961: При прямом суммировании, думаю, начиная с некоторого слагаемого при прибавлении сумма **вообще не меняется**.

Answer (score 2):

Суммировать следует с наименьших чисел, чтобы свести к минимуму накапливаемую погрешность. Посмотри мою небольшую лекцию.

Следующая задачка: подсчитать сумму 10 000 000 элементов ряда:

```
S = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 + 1/6 + . . . + 1/10000000.
```

По идее от перемены слагаемых сумма не меняется, т.е. если буду складывать в обратном порядке:

```
S = 1/10000000 + 1/9999999 + 1/9999998 + . . . + 1/3 + 1/2 + 1
```

то сумма должна быть такой же. Это верно для классической арифметики. Но мы имеем дело с компами, в которых заложена дискретная арифметика. Напишем нижеследующий код и скомпилируем его:

```
program Summa;

var s:single; i:longint;

begin

s:=0.0;
for i:=1 to 10000000 do s:=s+1.0/i; //подсчет суммы S = 1 + 1/2 +...+ 1/10000000

Writeln(s:0:2); //вывод результата на экран

s:=0.0;
for i:=10000000 downto 1 do s:=s+1.0/i; //подсчет суммы S = 1/10000000 +...+ 1/2 + 1

Writeln(s:0:2) //вывод результата на экран

end.
```

На экране будут такие результаты:

```
15.40

16.69
```

Результаты разные. В чем дело? Какая сумма из них более достоверна? И какая отсюда мораль?

Проблема заключается в конечности представления чисел в компе. Для данных типа single отводится 4 байта, в которых 1 бит отведен под знак, 8 бит – под двоичную степень, а оставшиеся 23 бита – под мантиссу ==> точность представления чисел ограничена 23 битами или 7-8 значащими десятичными цифрами. Т.е. в комп можно еще записать число 7.7777777 или 7.7777778, но никак не 7.7777777000000000007777777 – такое число просто округляется/обрезается до 23 бит для мантиссы.

Для того, чтобы проще объяснить работу нашего вышеприведенного примера, допустим, что точность чисел ограничена 2 значащими числами. Тогда в цикле подсчета суммы в прямом направлении имеем:

```
Проход 1: s := 0.0 + 1.0/1.0 = 1.0

Проход 2: s := 1.0 + 1.0/2.0 = 1.5

Проход 3: s := 1.5 + 1.0/3.0 = 1.5 + 0.33333333… --> 1.8 (округление до 2 цифр)

.

.

.

Проход 100: s := s + 1.0/100.0 = s + 0.01… --> s (округление и потеря младших цифр)

Проход 101: s := s + 1.0/101.0 = s + 0.0099… --> s (округление и потеря младших цифр)

.

.

.
```

При такой точности после 100-го прохода (фактически еще раньше) сумма в цикле будет адекватной `s := s + 0.0` из-за выбрасывания младших цифр в накапливаемой сумме.

Если же проделывать в обратном направлении:

```
Проход 1: s := 0.0 + 1.0/10000000.0 = 0.0000001 (результат сохраняется до 2 значащих цифр)

Проход 2: s := 0.0000001 + 1.0/9999999.0 = 0.0000001+ 0.00000010000001…--> 0.0000002

Проход 3: s := 0.0000002 + 1.0/9999998.0 = 0.0000001+ 0.00000010000002…--> 0.0000003

.

.

.
```

то мы получим более достоверную сумму. Кстати, если декларировать для s тип уже не single (одинарной точности), а double (двойной точности – 8 байт), то на экран будет выведено следующее:

```
16.70

16.70.
```

Но если же суммировать для бOльшего числа элементов (к примеру, до 100000000000000 элементов), то опять могут возникнуть искажения.

Мораль: для суммирования данных с большим разбросом значений подсчет суммы следует начинать с наименьших элементов, для того чтобы свести к минимуму потерю информации из-за дискретной природы данных, представляемых в компе.

---

И еще что бы посоветовал - раз ряд знакопеременный, то обычно стоило бы суммировать разности соседних элементов, так будет аккуратнее. Но для 1/(m*m) это, наверное, неактуально.

Comment: Вот теперь всё понятно!!! Спасибо, Валентин, за потраченное на меня время, наверняка и другим будет полезно такое разъяснение.  

Осталось только понять главное. Вот Вы говорите: "...так будет аккуратнее. Но для 1/(m*m) это, наверное, неактуально."  

Как же узнать - когда и как аккуратнее и актуальнее?! Как сравнивать разные алгоритмы и с чем. Неужели IEEE-754 даёт гарантии для бесконечных рядов и иррациональных чисел?

Comment: Суммировать разности стоит для очень близко стоящих друг к другу соседних элементов. Просто (эмпирически так предполагаю) не стоит тратить дополнительные усилия на усложнение кода для данной задачи. IEEE-754 не дает гарантий абсолютной точности. Можно лишь постараться свести к минимуму издержки дискретной арифметики

Answer (score 1):

[[@qqqq1961](/users/24440/qqqq1961)](/users/24440/qqqq1961), боюсь тут все сложнее, чем Вам кажется.

Внимательно посмотрите на простую программу, ее результаты и
сравненние их с подсчетом в `bc` с точностью 40 знаков.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <math.h>

#define __S_PI(x) # x
#define _S_PI(x) __S_PI(x)
#define S_PI _S_PI(M_PI)

int 
main(int ac, char *av[]) 
{ 
  printf ("M_PI = %.16f M_PI ** 2 = %.16f  (math.h: %s)\n", 
          M_PI, M_PI * M_PI, S_PI);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}

avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ gcc c.c
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./a.out 
M_PI = 3.1415926535897931 M_PI ** 2 = 9.8696044010893580  (math.h: 3.14159265358979323846)
End
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ bc
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
scale=40
3.1415926535897931 * 3.1415926535897931
9.86960440108935774884804450080761
3.14159265358979323846 * 3.14159265358979323846
9.8696044010893586188178821328931344231716
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$
```

Заметили, что доверять можно только 16 десятичным знакам (15 после запятой)?

Особо посмотрите, как падает точность после умножения (`M_PI * M_PI`).

Другими словами, точность вычислений с double на самом-то деле ограничена
точностью аппаратуры.

Отсутсвие ПРАВИЛЬНОГО ОКРУГЛЕНИЯ и приводит к странным результатам
(особенно при подсчете суммы, начиная с больших членов).

Comment: Да, заметил.
>Заметили, что доверять можно только 16 десятичным знакам 

Думаю, что столько знаков после умножения не нужно, если исходные 16 знаков и сумма ряда, видимо, тоже не должна превышать 16.  
Даже если сопроцессор, как я читал, использует 80.  
>3.1415926535897931 * 3.1415926535897931 = 9.86960440108935774884804450080761

Comment: @qqqq1961, да это все к вопросу -- *насколько можно доверять**

    Limit = (M_PI*M_PI)/12;
    ...
    Summa = ...
    ...
    Error = Limit - Summa;

вот таким вычислениям?

Понятно же, что младшие разряды как у `Limit`, так и у `Summa` недостоверны.

Comment: Понятно же, что младшие разряды как у Limit, так и у Summa недостоверны.  

Эй, эй! Что значит недостоверны?! После какой степени ошибки данные вычисления врут? 10 в-4? 10 в-14? Вы говорите вообще про точность вычисления суммы, даже при, скажем, 1000 членов или только про близкие к концу double значения?  

И что конкретно плохого в:   
    Limit = (M_PI*M_PI)/12;   
    Summa = ...   
    Error = Limit - Summa;?  
Как еще можно считать если не нужна предельная дочность?

Comment: @qqqq1961, к сожалению я не могу конкретно ответить на Ваши вопросы.

--

Кое-что можно прочесть [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112953/) (или нагуглить другие материалы...).

Также можно надеяться, что кто-нибудь на ХК достаточно компетентен и не ленив...

В любом случае, позвольте привести еще один "отрицательный" пример:

    double lim1 = (M_PI * M_PI) / 12,
      lim2 = (M_PI / 12) * M_PI;
    printf ("lim1 = %.16f lim2 = %.16f\n", lim1, lim2);
    
    lim1 = 0.8224670334241132 lim2 = 0.8224670334241131

Ну и с каким из `lim` сравнивать правильно? 

(подозреваю, что со вторым).

Comment: @qqqq1961, @avp: Угу, и вот ещё туда же [классическая статья](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) (на неё есть ссылка в статье на Хабре).

Comment: @qqqq1961, кстати, обратил внимание, что Вы упомянули о 80 разрядах сопроцессора, когда шла речь о доверии к 16 разрядам.

--

Я писал о *десятичных* разрядах (цифрах, которые мы печатаем). В формате `double` мантисса содержит 53 (в памяти реально хранятся 52) *двоичных* разрядов. 

Когда говорят о расширенном (80 разрядов) формате сопроцесора, то речь идет **не о десятичных** разрядах, а об общем количестве (мантисса + экспонента + знак) двоичных разрядов (всего будет храниться 10 8-ми битных байт). А под мантиссу (если не изменяет память) там используется 64 бита.

Comment: Всё же поясните плиз... что теперь даже при "бытовых" вычислениях так нельзя делать:
  
    Limit = (M_PI*M_PI)/12; 
    Summa = ...   
    Error = Limit - Summa; ? 
 
Нужно теперь всегда всё "взад" считать?!

Comment: Ну почему же нельзя?

Считайте на здоровье. Только помните, что доверять можно только 15-ти (десятичным) значащим цифрам.

Соответсвенно, действия с величинами отличающимися где-то на 12 - 14 порядков смысла уже не имеют.