# Найти среднее или приближенное к среднему число из списка

Tags: python

Есть список с числами. Как правильно найти число как можно ближе стоящее к средине списка?

```
list_nums = [5, 7, 10, 13, 17]
```

В данном случае это число 11, но посколько его нет ближе всего к нему стоит 10.

Comment: Первый раз не коректно описал задачу. Средне арифметическое я знал как высчитать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import statistics
>>> avg  = statistics.mean(list_nums)  # среднее 
>>> min(list_nums, key=lambda num: abs(num - avg))  # приближённое к среднему
10
```

`lambda num: abs(num - avg)` это функция, которая выражает понятие *"приближённое к среднему"* — чем это значение меньше тем ближе к среднему (при нуле совпадает со средним). Можно имя этой функции дать:

```
def distance(a, b):
    return abs(a - b)
```

Если представить, что точки лежат на линии, то `distance` возвращает  [Евклидову метрику](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) -- длину отрезка между точками. Именно поэтому используется [`abs()` функция, которая возвращает абсолютное значение](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs):  `abs(5 - 11) == abs(17 - 11) == 6` в данном случае, числа `5` и `17` на одном расстоянии от среднего `11`.

```
min(list_nums, key=lambda num: distance(num, avg))
```

`min()` возвращает такое число из `list_nums` списка, которое ближе всего к `avg` находится по метрике, определяемой `distance()`.

- [Зачем нужны Lambda-функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/534344/23044)
- [Как работают lambda-функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/612763/23044)
- [Реализация min / max Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584614/23044)

---

[`statistics.mean(L)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) является более точной по сравнению с наивной `sum(L)/len(L)` формулой, если вы хотите числа с плавающей точкой поддерживать:

```
>>> list_nums = [1e50, 1, -1e50] * 1000
>>> sum(list_nums) / len(list_nums)
0.0
>>> statistics.mean(list_nums)
0.3333333333333333
```

`statistics.mean()` не так работает, но для примера было бы достаточно: [`math.fsum(list_nums) / len(list_nums)`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/370601/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be#comment371094_370601).

Comment: Класс!!! Но не мог бы ты нубу расписать проще. А то вроде как и понимаю, но не до конца. Или может из-за abs, в нодобность которого я не до конца вьезжаю

Comment: @je_inc: добавил объяснение

Answer (score 2):

```
In [58]: avg = sum(list_nums)/len(list_nums)

In [59]: min([(x,abs(x-avg)) for x in list_nums], key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
Out[59]: 10
```

Пошаговый разбор:

```
In [60]: [(x,abs(x-avg)) for x in list_nums]
Out[60]:
[(5, 5.4),
 (7, 3.4000000000000004),
 (10, 0.40000000000000036),
 (13, 2.5999999999999996),
 (17, 6.6)]
```

далее находим кортеж с минимальной разницей:

```
In [61]: min([(x,abs(x-avg)) for x in list_nums], key=lambda x: x[1])
Out[61]: (10, 0.40000000000000036)
```

и выбираем первый элемент кортежа:

```
In [62]: min([(x,abs(x-avg)) for x in list_nums], key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
Out[62]: 10
```

---

вот очень элегантная [версия, предложенная @jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692629/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0/692637?noredirect=1#comment1024531_692637)

```
min(list_nums, key=lambda num: abs(num - avg))
```

---

Альтернативный вариант:

```
avg = sum(list_nums)/len(list_nums)
x = list_nums[0]

for i in list_nums:
    if abs(i - avg) < abs(x - avg):
        x = i

print(x)
```

Comment: ты крут, отдельное спс за подробное разъяснение, а то еще нуб, в сокращенной форме тяжеловато код читать

Comment: Можно упросить `min()` вызов:  `min(list_nums, key=lambda num: abs(num - avg))`. Для float sum/len формула может быть неточной. Можно statistics.mean использовать

Comment: @jfs, спасибо! `min(list_nums, key=lambda num: abs(num - avg))` - очень элегантно!