# Неправильно работает программа по нахождению среднего арифметического

Tags: python

```
a =[]
n= 3
num=0
summ=0
avrg=0
for i in range (0,n):
    a.append (int(input()))
if a[i] < 0:
    num = num + 1;
if a[i] < 0:
    summ = summ + a[i];

avrg=summ/num

print (avrg)
```

в результате дает последнее число, а не среднее арифметическое всех чисел массива

Comment: Во-первых смещения не хватает, у строк if которые должно быть смещение на уровне тела цикла. Во-вторых судя по коду вычисляется среднее только отрицательных чисел. А так программа в остальном вроде правильно выглядит.

Comment: Arty OneSoul, спасибо, не хватало отступов, вы мне очень помогли!

Comment: p.s.неправильно задал вопрос, нужно было СА всех отрицательных, а вы и так все поняли. Снимаю шляпу.

Comment: @toxicarchont `>>> nums = list(filter(lambda x: x < 0, array))
>>> sum(nums) / len(nums)`

Comment: связанный вопрос [Найти среднее или приближенное к среднему число из списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/692629/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы хотите каждое вводящие число тестировать на отрицательность и *только тогда*  увеличить их сумму и количество.

Так как вы делаете это *сразу* после загрузки каждого числа, вам *не нужно сохранять их в массиве*. Тоже не надо инициализировать переменную avrg:

```
n = 3
num = 0
summ = 0

for __ in range (0, n):
    a = int(input())
    if a < 0:
        num += 1
        summ += a

if num != 0:    
    avrg = summ / num
    print (avrg)
else:
    print ('Нет хи одного отрицательного числа.')
```

Примечания:

1. В цикле `for` нам не надо переменной, потому что мы ее *не будем использовать* - и так вместо `i` пишем `__`.
2. Мы будем делить на `num` - это возможно только для *ненулевого* значения, потому заключительный `if`-тест.

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, у вас сейчас условия не входят в цикл. То есть выполняются только по последнему значению `i` на выходе из цикла. Во вторых, избыток условных конструкций. В третьих, можно записать короче. В четвертых, избыточное использование точек с запятой. Они не нужны, если конструкции указываются на разных строках.

В итоге, должно получиться следующее:

```
a = []
n = 3
num=0
summ=0
avrg=0
for i in range (0,n):
    a.append (int(input()))
    if a[i] < 0:
        num += 1
        summ += a[i]

avrg=summ/num
print (avrg)
```